# Radio react-bootstrap not invoking onClick event

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am creating web application with React.JS and react-bootstrap.

What I want to do is when user click on below

```
<Radio name="radioGroup" onChange={console.log("hello")} inline></Radio>
```

then console log will get output as

```
hello
```

But I am not getting output the as expected.

**Whole code**

Function which will be called when user click

```
  renderApptype(data) {
    if(data!=null){
      const id=data.id;
      return (
        <tr key={data.id}>
          <td key={data.id}>
            <Radio name="radioGroup" onChange={console.log("hello")} inline></Radio>
          </td>
        </tr>
      );
    }
  }
```

Render

```
            <table className="table">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>App Type</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <FormGroup>
                  { this.props.data != null ? this.props.data.map(this.renderApptype) : null }
                </FormGroup>
              </tbody>
            </table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**the solution is writing**

```
onChange={() => {console.log("hello")}}
```

**why does it work like that?**
onChange get an event handler, which is a function, to execute when the `onChange` event happens. you didn't give the onChange a function, u just gave it a block.

**a better solution would be:**

```
const handleOnChangeEvent = () => {
  console.log("hello")
}
```

onChange={handleOnChangeEvent}

btw, in your render function, I would change the

```
this.props.data != null
```

to:

```
this.props.data !== null
```

read about === in javascript.

Comment: out of curiosity how we can pass argument in 

 onChange={handleOnChangeEvent}

Comment: we would write: onChange={(parameter1, parameter2) => {handleOnChangeEvent(parameter1, parameter2}}

Answer (score 0):

For that event to work you would need to bind it.

Try it this way:

`onChange={() => console.log("hello")}`

You can also find more information on how to [Handle Events on React](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html)